# Error loading FTDI dylib on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, dylib, xojo

I developed an application in Xojo that uses a third party library to control a device. It works on one mac, but then when I try to run it on the other it gives me the following error:

```
Application Specific Information:
dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries

Dyld Error Message:
  Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libftd2xx.1.2.2.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/USER/Downloads/*/libuFCoder.dylib
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
/usr/local/lib/libftd2xx.1.2.2.dylib: stat() failed with errno=62
/usr/local/lib/libftd2xx.1.2.2.dylib: stat() failed with errno=62
```

The Macs are both updated with the latest OSX El Capitan, and have the FTDI drivers installed. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How do you address the lib file in the declare statement, i.e. which exact path/name do you use? And what's the actual dylib's path and name? Also, can you supply an official download reference to the dylib? Which Xojo version?

Comment: The lib file is addressed with a full path, not relative:
/User/Alex/Downloads/Project/libuFCoder.dylib

Xojo version 2006 v1.1 
dylib download link: http://dld.is.d-logic.net/index.php/libraries-download/Latest-libs/ufcoder-libs-v-39127z?format=raw

Comment: Don't use an absolute path. Use a relative one, starting from your app's Contents/MacOS folder. Even better, place the dylib into your app's Frameworks or MacOS folder, and you won't need to use any path but only the lib's file name in the declare.

Answer (score 1):

I have installed the drivers on El Capitan and it worked for me, even with an absolute path with Xojo 2012.21. Try reinstalling the D2XX 1.2.2 driver in /usr/local/lib (as instructed in the ReadMe file) and remove all old "libftd2xx" files.
Also remember you need to install D2xxHelper for the driver to work properly on El Capitan.

To check if the uFCoder library properly links against libftd2xx, open the Terminal, type "otool -L <path to the uFCoder lib>"; the 2nd line should start with "/usr/local/lib/libftd2xx.1.2.2.dylib".

HTH